# Calculating Normal CDF Using Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to find P(X<0.5) for X~N(0,1) using integration without technology or polynomials to help with the integrals. Seems like I learned this method in grad school, but can't remember the last steps and haven't found anything online about it yet. I have:
\begin{align}
P(X<0.5)
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{0.5} e^{-x^2/2}dx \\
& = 0.5 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{0.5}e^{-x^2/2}dx \int_{0}^{0.5}e^{-y^2/2}dy} \\
& = 0.5 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{0.5}\int_{0}^{0.5}e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2}}dxdy} \\
& = 0.5 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{0.5\sec(\theta)}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}rdrd\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{0.5\csc(\theta)}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}rdrd\theta} \\
& = 0.5 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sqrt{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}1-e^{\frac{-(0.5\sec(\theta))^2}{2}}d\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}1-e^{\frac{-(0.5\csc(\theta))^2}{2}}d\theta}
\end{align}

Dunno where to go from there. Help please.

Comment: Do know that the integral $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ can not be expressed using standard mathematical functions? (It can be done via the ```error-function``` though, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29+dx+from+-+infty+to+1%2F2)).

Comment: That "method" seems to be the trick to evaluate the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ by converting it to polar coordinates.  It does not work for calculating the integral from $0$ to a finite value.  It is likely that there is no closed form for your integral except in terms of special functions.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. Maybe the trick works for some other Gaussian or a Beta with a finite upper bound and I'm just confusing that with the Normal.